# Is the nerve of a symmetric monoidal category a K-theory space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, algebraic-k-theory

It's an amazing fact that if the $C$ is a symmetric monoidal category so that its components form a group, then $NC$ is an infinite loop space. Now if we have a Waldhausen category $D$, a category with distinguished cofibrations and weak equivalences, we can also construct an infinite loop-space via the S - construction.

Are these two constructions equivalent? In other words, given such a $C$ can I construct a Waldhausen category so the S - construction gives something weakly equivalent to $NC$? And if $D$ is a Waldhausen category can I construct a symmetric monoidal category so its nerve is weakly equivalent to the S - construction?

Comment: They are equivalent. This is a remark in Waldhausen's paper "Algebraic k-theory of spaces." The way to see it is kind of cryptically phrased "to see [this]... it suffices to note that the two spectra can be combined into a connective bi-spectrum." +1, I would also like to see this in detail